# When I define a Piecewise function containing a solution to a partial differential equation, the function cannot be evaluated numerically

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I need to find an integral, in which there is a function

```
YO [x_] = 
  Sum[E^(((I h PI)/(λ f))x^2) Subscript[Y, h][x, z = 13.5], {h, - 5, - 1}] /. s
```

where `Subscript[Y, h][x, z]` is a solution of partial differential equation.

I run `YO [3]` in the positive interval of {x, 0, 30} and find that I can get a numerical value. After that, I want to extend the domain of `YO`  to `{x, -30, 30}`. The value of negative interval upper function and positive interval are symmetric. So I manually defined a piecewise function, and tried it with `Piecewise` and `If` functions. When the function `YO[x]` is in the negative interval, the value is equal to `YO[Abs[x]]`, but I found that after calculation, running `YO[3]` can not get the numerical value, so I can only return `YO[3]` itself.

Based on the above situation, it is OK for me to integrate with the non expanded `YO[x]`, but if I integrate with the expanded `YO[x]` with `Piecewise` or `If` function, I get the error:

> the sampling point is non numerical at a certain point.

At the same time, It also report errors when I find the maximum value of the integral result `g[xo, zo]` by `FindArgMax`, Whether it is the function of `YO` before expansion or the function of `YO` after integration, It will report an error that the function value is not a real number. But my function value is the square after taking the modulus, which must be a real number. The relevant knowledge that I have been looking for for a long time these days has not been solved, so I would like to know what's wrong with my code.

In addition, I can get the specific value by directly integrating the function `YO[x]` which is not expanded, but I can't get the numerical value by integrating the function `YO[x]` which is expanded by `Piecewise` and `If`, so I can only get the function formula which contains subscript `[Y, h][x,z]`.

This is my program for solving partial differential equations, and it is proved that the solution is completely correct.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
θ = 0;
λ = 1.2398/(19.5 10^3);
f = 4.72 10^3;
Subscript[δ, 1] = 1.274/10^6;
Subscript[δ, 2] = 4.304/10^6;
Subscript[bt, 1] = 5.254/10^9;
Subscript[bt, 2] = 2.435/10^7;
χ1 = -2 Subscript[δ, 1] + 2 I Subscript[bt, 1];
χ2 = -2 Subscript[δ, 2] + 2 I Subscript[bt, 2];
Δχ = χ1 - χ2;
k = 2 (π/λ);
Table[β[b] = -((2 (b x) Sin[θ])/f) - ((b x)/f)^2, {b, -5, 5}];
Table[χ[a] = (Δχ (1 - (-1)^Abs[a]))/(2 I a π), {a, -10, -1}];
Table[χ[a] = (Δχ (1 - (-1)^Abs[a]))/(2 I a π), {a, 1, 10}];
Table[χ[a] = (χ1 + χ2)/2, {a, 0, 0}];

eqns = 
  Join[
    Table[
      (Sin[θ] + (h x)/f) D[Subscript[Y, h][x, z], x] + 
         Cos[θ] D[Subscript[Y, h][x, z], z] == 
      ((I Pi)
        (β[h] Subscript[Y, h][x, z] +
           Sum[χ[h - l] Subscript[Y, l][x, z], {l, -5, 5}]))/λ, 
      {h, -5, 5}], 
    Table[Subscript[Y, h][x, 0] == If[h == 0, 1, 0], {h, -5, 5}]]; 

s = 
  NDSolve[eqns,
    Table[Subscript[Y, h][x, z], {h, -5, 5}],
    {x, 0, 30}, {z, 0, 30},
    Method ->
      {"MethodOfLines",
       "SpatialDiscretization" ->
         {"TensorProductGrid", 
          "MaxPoints" -> 100, "MinPoints" -> 100, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4},
      "TemporalVariable" -> z}];
```

This is my program to define YO[x]

```
YO[x_?NumericQ] :=
  Piecewise[
    {{Sum[
        E^((I h π)/(λ f) x^2) Subscript[Y, h][x, z = 13.5],
        {h, -5, -1}],
      20 >= x >= 0}, 
     {Sum[
        E^((I h π)/(λ f) x^2) Subscript[Y, h][(Abs[x]), z = 13.5], 
        {h, -5, -1}],
      0 > x >= -20}},
    {x, -20, 20}] /. s
```

And this is what I want to do: integrate, find the maximum of `g[xo, zo]` and plot the density around zo at the maximum

```
f1[xo_?NumericQ, zo_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(E^(I k zo) YO[x] E^(((I k) x^2)/(2 zo))
        E^(((I k) xo^2)/(2 zo))
        E^(-(((I k) x xo)/zo)))/(I λ zo^0.5), {x, -20, 
     20}] /. s;

g[xo_?NumericQ, zo_?NumericQ] := Abs[f1[xo, zo]^2];

FindArgMax[
  {g[xo, zo], -20 <= xo <= 20 && 3000 <= zo <= 5000}, 
  {{xo, 0}, {zo, 4000}}]

DensityPlot[g[xo, zo], {xo, -20, 20}, {zo, 3000, 5000}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

But in fact, both the `NIntegrate` and `FindArgMax` will give me an error. The message from `NIntegrate` tells me that some values are not numerical, and the message from `FindArgMax` tells me that some values are not real. But it's obvious that the absolute value followed by the square must be real and numerical.

In addition, when I integrate with the unexpanded `YO[x]`, I can integrate and draw a graph, but I never succeed in finding the maximum value.

This is my unexpanded `YO[x]`, which is defined over `{x, 0, 30}`. With this function, I can run `YO[3]` to calculate the specific value, but if I expand the domain to `{x, - 30,30}`, which is the piecewise function in the previous code, I can only get itself by running `YO[3]`.

```
YO[x_]=
  Sum[E^(((I h Pi)x^2)/(λ f)) Subscript[Y, h][x, z = 13.5], 
  {h, -5, -1}] /. s;
```

I wonder if this is the reason why plotting after integration produces complaints about non-numerical values, but no matter which `YO[x]` I use to calculate the maximum of `g[xo,zo]`, it always complains about non-numerical values.

Comment: Try the following toy example and think about what's wrong: `s = {{aaa -> 1}};
(aaa /. s) > 2`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So sometimes the output result is `{a}`, which will be considered as non-numerical in some functions, because it is in the form of a list?

Comment: Yes. Another example: `FindArgMax[{{-2 x^2 - 3 x + 5}}, x]`.

Comment: I see, `Findargmax` can calculate the list, that is `{eq}`, but `{{}}` is not a list or a number, so it cannot be calculated. @xzczd

Comment: I don't think so. `FindArgMax[{-2 x^2 - 3 x + 5}, x]` works probably because it's treated as a special case of the last documented syntax `FindArgMax[{f,cons},{x,y,…}]`.

Comment: @xzczd That's what I want to say, it's my fault for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

Your piecewise definition for `YO` is improperly written. However, I would recommend not using `Piecewise` at all. I would rewrite your code like this:

```
θ = 0;
λ = 1.2398/(19.5 10^3);
f = 4.72 10^3;
Subscript[δ, 1] = 1.274/10^6;
Subscript[δ, 2] = 4.304/10^6;
Subscript[bt, 1] = 5.254/10^9;
Subscript[bt, 2] = 2.435/10^7;
χ1 = -2 Subscript[δ, 1] + 2 I Subscript[bt, 1];
χ2 = -2 Subscript[δ, 2] + 2 I Subscript[bt, 2];
Δχ = χ1 - χ2;
k = 2 (π/λ);
Table[β[b] = -((2 (b x) Sin[θ])/f) - ((b x)/f)^2, {b, -5, 5}];
Table[χ[a] = (Δχ (1 - (-1)^Abs[a]))/(2 I a π), {a, -10, -1}];
Table[χ[a] = (Δχ (1 - (-1)^Abs[a]))/(2 I a π), {a, 1, 10}];
Table[χ[a] = (χ1 + χ2)/2, {a, 0, 0}];

eqns = 
  Join[
    Table[
      (Sin[θ] + (h x)/f) D[Subscript[Y, h][x, z], x] + 
       Cos[θ] D[Subscript[Y, h][x, z], z] == 
      ((I Pi) 
        (β[h] Subscript[Y, h][x, z] + 
          Sum[χ[h - l] Subscript[Y, l][x, z], {l, -5, 5}]))/λ,
      {h, -5, 5}],
    Table[Subscript[Y, h][x, 0] == If[h == 0, 1, 0], {h, -5, 5}]];
```

The following contains modifications to your code.

```
s =
  NDSolve[eqns,
    Table[Subscript[Y, h], {h, -5, 5}], {x, 0, 30}, {z, 0, 30},
    Method ->
      {"MethodOfLines",
       "SpatialDiscretization" ->
         {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 100,
          "MinPoints" -> 100, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4},
       "TemporalVariable" -> z}];

Clear[YO]
YO[x_?NumericQ /; (0 > x >= -20)] := YO[-x]
YO[x_?NumericQ] = 
  First[Sum[E^((I h π)/(λ f) x^2) Subscript[Y, h][x, 13.5], {h, -5, -1}] /. s];
```

Then `YO` behaves as a even function over the domain [-20, 20]:

```
YO /@ {-20, -3, 3, 20} // Column
```

[image: result]

I think there are (possibly many) other problems with your code, but maybe this will help you to move on and correct them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which is of great help to me. You use the `First` to change the output {a} into a, Let me know what I made by outputting errors. Although `YO[x]` has been able to get the value, but I still have some things I don't understand. For example, in NDSolve, you replace `subscript [Y, h] [x, z]` with `subscript [Y, h]`, and then you can get the value of YO [x]. I still don't understand it after I looked up some information.

Comment: @shrocat Try the following toy example and think about what's wrong: `func[x_]=x+1; f[1] /. f[x]->func[x]`, then try the following and think about why it works: `func[x_]=x+1; f[1] /. f -> func` .

Comment: Hello,ba zhu. I feel that I understand something, but I don't seem to understand it. The following function `/.` Replaces the head, so the numerical result can be obtained. If the previous replacement is replaced by `func[x_ ] = x + 1; f[1] /. f[x_ ]- > func [x]` or `func[x] = x + 1; f [1] /. F [x]_ ]- > func [x]` can also get numerical results, so I think it should be a variable problem?

Comment: @shrocat You need to add `@xzczd` in the comment or I won't get the reminder. Then, something is missing in your second sample, please double check it.

Comment: @xzczd  Oh,I made some mistakes.It should be `func[x] = x + 1; f[1] /. f[x_] -> func[x]` and `func[x_] = x + 1; f[1] /. f -> func`.

Comment: @shrocat Now check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67036/1871 Then, since you can read Chinese, check this: https://note.youdao.com/ynoteshare1/index.html?id=77b86cb08aaf29ce8747990c9e717298&type=note

Comment: @xzczd Thank you!