# How do you get substitution to recognize a derivative?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, pattern-matching, semantic-matching

I have a simple expression involving a derivative:

```
x[t_] = Q/T[t];
Simplify[Derivative[1][x][t] /. Q -> x T[t]]
```

That produces:$$-\frac{x T'[t]}{T[t]}$$I have another relation: $T=a^{-1}$.  When I make the substitution, I get this:

```
Simplify[-((x*Derivative[1][T][t])/T[t]) /. T[t] -> 1/a[t]]
```

$$-x a[t] T'[t]$$

But what I want is this:
$$x \frac{a[t]}{a'[t]}$$I know I can force the issue with an additional substitution of $T'[t]=-a'[t]^{-1}$, but it seems to me that I've already given Mathematica everything it needs to make that substitution on it's own.
How do I force MMa to recognize this kind of substitution in the derivative?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67036/1871 There should be more.

Comment: I can't really follow any of your steps. First of all, if you want `Derivative` to take substitutions into consideration, then you probably need to make them before applying that function. Additionally, did you intend `x` and `x[t]` to be different?

Comment: I understand that I can go backwards in the derivation and make the substitution before I calculate the derivative, but that makes the derivation more confusing.  I'd like to make the substitution in the last step so that it's very clear how I got to this point.

Comment: (1) Why `x`, which is treated like a number, instead of `x[t]` in your substitution? (= Marco’s question) (2) The syntax of `Derivative[order][func][arg]` requires that a function `f` be substituted for `func`, not an expression like `f[t]` that represents the value of a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make the functional transformation via substitutions, without destroying the symbolic `T[t]` by giving it a definition, and the calculus will be done automatically:

```
x[t_] = Q/T[t];
Simplify[Derivative[1][x][t] /. Q -> X T[t]]
% /. T -> (1/a[#1] &)
```

[image]

One can change the `X` to `x` if desired. It seems undesirable from a programming point of view to have a definition of `x` as a function lurking while treating same symbol later as a different sort of object.  If you want to switch between `x` being a dependent and independent variable, which I sometimes do when transforming differential equations, the following sequence of transformations avoids giving `x` a definition:

```
Derivative[1][x][t] /.
   x -> (Q/T[#] &) /.
  Q -> x T[t] /.
 T -> (1/a[#1] &)
```

If I need to use transformations repeatedly, I might save each in a variable like `x2T`, `Qsub`, `T2a`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this intuitively.  If $a$ is the inverse of $T$, then how did $a$ end up in the denominator?  Just looking at the equation, it seems like the result should be $$\frac {x\space a[t]}{a'[t]}$$That is, how come we don't get the inverse of $\frac{T'[t]}{T[t]}$?

Comment: @Quarkly What do you mean by inverse, inverse function or reciprocal?  If reciprocal, the derivative of $T[t]=1/a[t]$ is $T’[t]=- a’[t]/a[t]^2$ by the Chain and power rules. How would the derivative $a’[t]$ end up in the denominator if $T’[t]$ is in the numerator? The Chain rule never puts the derivative in the denominator. And the power rule puts an $a[t]^2$ in the denominator, which combines with the power of $a[t]$ from $T[t]$ in the denominator. (The inverse function theorem has a derivative in the denominator, though.)

Comment: I guess that should read 'reciprocal'.  OK.  I see it now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You are making a mistake. If `T[t] = 1/a[t]` , then `T'[t] = D[(1/a[t]), t] = -a'[t] / a[t]^2`

Further, replacement is a wholly structural operation, it can not do derivatives. To achieve what you want, you would have to set `T[t]= 1/a[t]`

```
Clear[a, T]
T[t_] = 1/a[t];
x T'[t]/T[t]
```

[image]

Comment: I get `x a[t] Derivative[1][T][t]` when I execute that statement.  Still can't produce the negative sign.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, I corrected it: `T[t_]` instead of `T[t]`

Comment: Same question as below.  If $T=\frac{1}{a}$, then how come the $a[t]$ term is still in the denominator of this result?  I would expect the numerator and denominator to switch places when there's an inverse relation.

Comment: Look at the derivative of 1/a.