How to do substitution of a function by another function in derivatives
Simplifying my problem, I have the expression D[f[x], x], and I want to substitute f[x] with a[x]+b[x].
The usual substitutions do not work ofc (and I understand why):
D[f[x ], x] /. {f[x] -> a[x]+b[x] } 
D[f[x ], x] /. {f -> a+b}

How to do it them in an elegant way?

See also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50845/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80241/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/243559/1871

To be more specific: func[x_] = a[x] + b[x]; D[f[x], x] /. f -> func

D[f[x ], x] will be evaluated before the substitution is done, resulting in:f'[x]. The substitution: {f[x] -> a[x]+b[x] } on f'[x]  will do nothing.
Therefore, you must prevent the early evaluation by e.g.: Hold
Hold[D[f[x], x]] /. {f[x] -> a[x] + b[x]} // ReleaseHold



I usually do
D[f[x], x] /. f -> Function[x, a[x] + b[x]]

or
D[f[x], x] /. f -> Function @@ {x, a[x] + b[x]}

The second allows everything to be evaluated. Sometimes evaluation is what I want, and sometimes it is not what I want. For instance,
expression /. f -> Function @@ {vars, formula}

where vars and formula are symbols containing the list of variables and the computed formula I wish to substitute.
